# mysqldump over ssh and mysql restore - security issue?

Tags: security, ssh, mysql

I've just found a one liner to mirror a local mysql database on a remote server, over ssh:

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot zedatabase | ssh -p4551 geek@12.34.56.78 "mysql -udoom -pmySqlPassword zedatabase"
```

This is very handy, but something intrigues me:

is it secure to pass the mysqlPassword in the command?
(But if I just leave the -p mysql option without explicit password, the command doesn't work)

What are the risks there, I mean, I know that someone which has access on my local machine will be able to access the password
through the history;

but apart of that, can anyone else capture the output of the command (with a middle man attack or something like that), or is it ssh encrypted?

Comment: If someone managed to mount a man-in-the-middle attack against you, whether that's encrypted or not is moot - they see all the traffic in clear (including your complete database content).

Comment: What if I only use public key authentication, it seems that mitm attack are ineffective against that type of authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529530/is-man-in-the-middle-attack-a-security-threat-during-ssh-authentication-using-ke  In this case, the attacker would still see the database dump, but not the mysqlPassword of the remote database ?

Comment: "I know that someone which has access on my local machine will be able to access the password through the history" you can add whitespace at the beginning of the command